# Total Rolling Calendar Days per Group Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, cumulative-sum

I would like to calculate the rolling cumulative total of **all calendar days** a "station" is in operation. My dataset does not contain days when the station was not in operation. But I need to calculate the rolling total of calendar days each station was in operation from the Start Date.

I have provided code below that creates a dataframe that contains different stations and their operating days. I calculate the rolling cumulative operating days, now i need to find the rolling cumulative of the calendar days since the start date

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Date': ['2011-01-02','2011-01-04','2011-01-05',
              '2011-01-10','2011-01-14','2011-01-15',
              '2011-01-17','2011-01-19','2011-01-22'], 
     'Value': [2,4,66,22,1,2,4,7,9], 
     'Station_ID': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')

df

# this gives each stations rolling cumulative number of operating days
df['Rolling_Operating_Days'] = df.groupby('Station_ID')['Date'].rank(method='dense',ascending=True)
df
```

I would like the output to look like this:

As you can see, the "rolling calendar_days" starts on calendar day 1 of a "station_ID", then the cumulative rolling total is summed up.

So, looking at the dataset below, even though the station was only in operation for 4 or 5 days ("Rolling_Operating_Days") the total ("Rolling_Calendar_Days") calendar days was 9.

```
    Date    Value   Station_ID  Rolling_Operating_Days  Rolling_Calendar_Days
0   2011-01-02  2   A           1.0                             1.0
1   2011-01-04  4   A           2.0                             3.0
2   2011-01-05  66  A           3.0                             4.0
3   2011-01-10  22  A           4.0                             9.0
4   2011-01-14  1   B           1.0                             1.0
5   2011-01-15  2   B           2.0                             2.0
6   2011-01-17  4   B           3.0                             4.0
7   2011-01-19  7   B           4.0                             6.0
8   2011-01-22  9   B           5.0                             9.0
```

I would like to be able to calculate the **"Rolling_Calendar_Days"** column. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: you want `rolling_calendar_days` but you include the code to calculate it, so I'm not sure what the question is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish. The issue with your example is that if the start day is not 1 (2011-01-02). It would then start at 2 and not 1. The solution would be to use `pd.series.diff()` then `cumsum`

lets assume df_subset is:

```
    Date        Value   Station_ID  
1   2011-01-02  0.961571    A       
3   2011-01-04  -0.927761   A       
4   2011-01-05  0.340300    A       
9   2011-01-10  -1.805910   A       
13  2011-01-14  0.062959    B       
14  2011-01-15  -0.402931   B       
16  2011-01-17  0.696784    B       
18  2011-01-19  -0.039989   B       
21  2011-01-22  -0.547465   B
```

then you can:

```
# create a func for groupby
def myFunc(x):
    return x['Date'].diff().dt.days.replace(np.nan,1).cumsum()

# apply function to group and reset index
df_subset['Rolling_Calendar_Days'] = df_subset.groupby('Station_ID').apply(myFunc).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)



    Date         Value  Station_ID  Rolling_Calendar_Days
1   2011-01-02  0.961571    A        1.0
3   2011-01-04  -0.927761   A        3.0
4   2011-01-05  0.340300    A        4.0
9   2011-01-10  -1.805910   A        9.0
13  2011-01-14  0.062959    B        1.0
14  2011-01-15  -0.402931   B        2.0
16  2011-01-17  0.696784    B        4.0
18  2011-01-19  -0.039989   B        6.0
21  2011-01-22  -0.547465   B        9.0
```

this assumes that you want to start date to start at 1 and not 0

Comment: This works exactly the way I wanted. I have cleaned up the question to make more sense, I did a bad job explaining what I wanted before. Thanks!